# How do I set a custom cell for non databound TableCells

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am happily able to set the styling of my tableviewcells using the cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate, but I want to set the background of all the nonpopulated cells which are still on the screen

Answer (score 0):

hey, basically any cell which is part of your tableview belongs to a particular index and particular row

so incase you are not populating a particular section via data source - you can still get a reference to a cell in that indexPath by manually calling the cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate, and passing the section as well as row index

it returns you a cell. assign it to your private variable and edit it the way you want to.

Comment: I have tried this but because my data source is bound to the table (length of 5) any cells outside of that length return the error: index (10) beyond bounds (5)

Comment: tigermain - your question or your code is probably incorrect then. basically your tableview only has x number of rows (which you specify) via numberOfRowsInSection delegate. and if you specify the right number, then you can get a reference to ANY CELL IN ANY SECTION which exists

Comment: I define an array of strings, then return the length of this in numberOfRowsInSection. This then restricts the number of elements to 5 in this case, but the table view is large enough to display abut 10 records

Comment: okay, you cant get a reference to these extra cells then (because they are never instantiated by tableview data source). i think you should have mentioned this in your question clearly :-)

Comment: I did say for the NON-Databound cells in the title

Answer (score 0):

Use the `visibleCells` method on your table view. Then do what you wish to the cells.

Alternately, you could call `indexPathsForVisibleRows` to get just the index paths. Then call `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to get the cell corresponding to each index path.